# Pandas - calculating interaction between buyers and sellers

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

So I have a programming problem, which I am finding a little challenging. I have daily data for several years (located in Pandas DataFrame) on buyers and sellers ala. this:

```
            Seller  Buyer   Amount  
2012/11/13  Bank1   Bank2   15                              
2012/11/13  Bank1   Bank2   17             
2012/11/13  Bank5   Bank3   5              
2012/11/14  Bank4   Bank2   10                  
2012/11/14  Bank1   Bank3   22
```

Index is Pandas.DatetimeIndex.

I would like to calculate, on a month-level basis for each buying bank, what share of their total monthly volume comes from each seller, they have interacted with. So in the above case the output (preferably a DataFrame as well) would be:

```
Month       Seller  Buyer   Share   
2012/11     Bank1   Bank2   32/42                               
2012/11     Bank4   Bank2   10/42              
2012/11     Bank5   Bank3   5/27               
2012/11     Bank1   Bank3   22/27
```

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your desired output doesn't seem to match your input.

Comment: Agreed with DSM. I am getting something else with my code. @DSM, please give me a chance to answer if you'd be kind enough! :D

Comment: Sorry, that was a little sloppy. I have edited my question, so it should be correct now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have uploaded an IPython notebook to Github that should begin to answer your question. You can find it [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ericmjl/Stack-Overflow-Answers/blob/master/20140414%20Buyers%20and%20Sellers/Buyers%20and%20Sellers.ipynb).

The basic approach here is to do `DataFrame.groupby()` operations. Using the dummy data you provided, I first did `data.groupby('Buyer').sum()`, reset the index to the buyer, add back the sum as a "total" column, and finally divide.

I am not so sure on how to do the timeseries stuff (i.e. grouping by month when you only have full date info not split into year month date). If others have suggestions, please leave a comment so I can update the notebook and my answer!

Comment: Thanks! I solved the problem using groupby as you suggested, coupled with .resample('M', how='sum'), which apparently sums over months. Will upload the full code later

Comment: My pleasure. Thank you as well for the `resample` comment as well! Looking forward to seeing your full code! And if you haven't started using IPython's notebooks, I would also recommend it.